PHP 8.2 filesize() unable to read from directory
I have looked up what my issue would be with filesize() that cant read the file size of a file which is in a sub directory (/media/). Also file_exists() and is_readable() gave negative feedback. Directory and file permission 777. The best is that <img> is showing the image and get an echo of the file directory.. Least but not last, files are owned by same user. Tested with and without $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].
Thats my php file outside of sub directory /media:
$filename = '/media/photo.jpg';
//$filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/media/photo.jpg';

// Getting error filesize(): stat failed for /home/kingkong/media/photo.jpg
echo $filename . '<br>' . filesize($filename) . ' bytes<br>';

// File path is echod with else "The file /home/kingkong/media/photo.jpg is NOT ok.
if (file_exists($filename) || is_readable($filename)) {
    echo "The file $filename is ok";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename is not ok<br>";
}

// Image is rendered and show on browser.
echo '<img src="'.$filename.'"/>';


"in sub directory" /media/photo.jpg is not a sub-directory. It's at the root of your filesystem.

The php file is outside of /media

"Directory and file permission 777" Never do this.

I know, its for internal test if that was an issue.

if is_readable() gave negative feedback. maybe file is not ready for reading, Like when it's open for writing, or maybe it was opened and locked, but not closed, or other OS error like that.

Tested with several files and file types but same result. If the file is next to the php file, than it is ok and can read filesize(). Between, using PHP 8.2

To elaborate on what olivier said, you probably need something like $filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/media/photo.jpg';to get the full path to the file.

Thank you but same result filesize(): stat failed for /media/photo.jpg

What's the value of $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?

"/home/kingkong/"

Then the correct absolute path of the file is /home/kingkong/media/photo.jpg.

I have uploaded a random image which I have downloaded from the web and it worked. Now its confusing me much more. As I am working on a project and there are over 10k photos I am testing those to read. Checking over command line the is the file size available. Using exiftool also.

One of the images I am testing. It seems fine but dont get a result https://electronics.semaf.at/media/image/product/15528/lg/ESP32-S3-LCD-Touch-DevBoard-7-Zoll-Display-Xtensa-32-bit-Dual-Core-24GHz-WiFi-BT5.jpg

Oliver the absolute did not help too. It has only worked if php file and image was in same folder.

The && operator causes that you can't catch the error clear.
Separate conditions to get the clear error message:
$filename = '/media/photo.jpg';

if (!file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "The file $filename was not exist!<br>";
} elseif (!is_readable($filename)) {
    echo "The file $filename is not readable (locked or something else)<br>";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename is " . filesize($filename) . ' bytes<br>';
    echo '<img src="' . $filename . '"/>';
}


If I use only the if part with if (!file_exist... and add echo '<img src="' . $filename . '"/>'; below, the browser shows up the image :) That makes me crazy. If the file does not exist how it comes that the browser shows. Screenshot https://freeimage.host/i/dKoGAiu

When the file does not exist, you insert a placeholder image like <img alt="image not found" src="/media/image/static/notFound.jpg"> Some web sites use funny images for this case (notFound.jpg) so user does not feel bad. search for "funny not found image"

Note that you got file size before check that is it exist and is it readable. That cause to error in your code. my code handles the error by show a error message (or show image) to alert user and avoid user to confuse. But you should fix the problem later. you could check your file system to know is file exist? or why it's not available for read. you can make log to save this cases. If this case repeats again maybe you find when error occurs and what's the reason.
